# How do I move a <li> to the right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some things in a `<ul>`, but I need the last one to be all the way to the right. How do I put it there? (I need the dropdown to move to the right.)

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a class="btn" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i></a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: generally, you can add a `.pull-right` in bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split it into two navbars: one that is on the left and one that is floated right with `pull-right`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a class="btn" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a></li>
  <li><a class="btn" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Check out the example from Bootstrap's example site: http://examples.getbootstrap.com/navbar-fixed-top/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a class="btn" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i></a></li>
      <!--// add a class of .pull-right //-->        
     <li class="dropdown pull-right ">  
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/DBMNf/2/)

Comment: That did not work. I think my css is overriding it or something. Do you know some css I had do to the <ul> or <li> that will move it to the right?

Comment: whats it doing/not doing?

Comment: It doesn't do anything at all when I put it in

Answer (score 0):

relatively new to HTMl and CSS, but I solved a similar problem without having to make a duplicate menu bar. Simply 'float: right;' in the

tage you want to appear on the right. (Best to have them as the last

elements to maintain logical order.)

for example

Action

becomes 
Action
Repeat this for any elements you want on the right hand side. It will overwrite the defined float:left default.

Dropdown

Action

Another action

Something else here

Nav header

Separated link

One more separated link